# npm: How to extract dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

Using pip one can do:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This extracts all dependencies. Is there something similar for npm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `npm init` which will generate a `package.json` that includes the modules in your `node_modules` subdirectory.

If you don't need/want to generate a `package.json`, you could get the dependency tree via `npm ls`. You can adjust the depth to include only direct dependencies via `npm ls --depth=0`.